# Discord.js Internal Server Error when Editing Message

Tags: javascript, error-handling, discord, discord.js

I'm making a command that replies with an embed, then waits 5 seconds before editing the message to replace the embed and add 2 message action rows with 5 buttons each. Like this:

```
await interaction.reply({embeds:[embed]}
await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,5000)) // 5 second wait using a Promise
...
await interaction.editReply({components:[row,row2],embeds:[embed2]}) // Replaces the embed and adds the 2 rows
```

Is there any way to fix this? I understand that Internal Server Errors are Discord's fault, but without adding the rows it updates the message just fine? Are my rows too big? I'm not entirely sure, but if you know the answer then please reply.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting? Are you getting an error code from Discord? Or an error from your server-side code?

Comment: The error code is 500, and it's from discord because I don't usually implement my own error codes like this.

Answer (score 0):

To edit a Reply, you must fetch it but you are not fetching it and directly using `interaction.editReply` that's why you are getting that error

Use `deferReply()` it is best because once an interaction occurs you have 3 seconds to reply to it but if the program requires more time then `deferReply()` must be used to get more time (You get 15 minutes, FYI)

So do like this:

```js
await interaction.deferReply();

await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] })
await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 5000)) // 5 second wait using a Promise
await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed2], components: [row, row2] }) // Replaces the embed and adds the 2 rows
```